# PHP_printer to print duplex(dual sided) pages

Tags: php, printing

I am working on php_printer features since last week, I am using a KONICA MINOLTA C364SeriesPCL Printer installed on local server

1. Set the printer default properties to print dual side pages
2. Tried printing as a document, a pdf, separate pages n much more. It keeps on printing on new page. Is there any option to print on both side of a paper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is server side. Printing is handled client side. You need to configure your printer to print on both sides. Go into your printer and set it up to be duplex. How this is done will be dependent on the OS and printer driver.

FYI: I recall working with PHP, PDF, and printers when I needed to print custom size labels. Just in case you end up needing to add support for custom page sizes go to on Windows 7: Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers > click printer > Print server properties add appropriate form e.g. 6x6.

I hope that helps.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks, Is there any option to control print using php for duplex and single sided print?

Comment: There is none that I am aware of. That doesn't mean one could not be made. PHP is software, the browser is software, and the printer runs on software. The real issue is not PHP sending some sort of command but in the browsers and/or your pdf viewers ability to interpret such a command and for the printer to support it. You could print duplex with a blank odd page if necessary, but that isn't really pretty. Browsers are adding support for HTML print commands to control orphans, etc. Perhaps the following will help:  https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/printer-defaults-both-sides-reader.html